# Why the title of Erased use serif and sans-serif together as fonts?

Tags: erased

Here is the title of the series and the 9th episode. They used a combined fonts type. Is there any reason for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This](https://xn--n8jawt8ezc7925ag2wf.com/580.html) gives an analysis of the serif/sans-serif strokes. The later into the episodes, the more sans-serif strokes, but a conclusion is that there is no particular hidden meaning.

Comment: @sundowner I believe you can convert your comment into a great answer. That link pretty much answer the question unless you have more reference or thought.